# Setting a value from a selection with get

Tags: php, selection

I just need help with a few things. Firstly how would I get the data of a selection when posted.Like

```
$selection=$_GET['area'];
if ($selection="time"){
echo "Not working yet please come back at a later update.";
}
```

and also on that note, why is it displaying it even when there is no data sent over the form. I thank any and all help.

Comment: you need to give == for if condition please change it

Comment: change if ($selection=="time") instead of if ($selection="time")

Answer (score 1):

It must be `==` operator you have used `=` operator which is the assiging operator.You have to use `==` or `===` operator for comparisons.For more check [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) in php

```
$selection = trim($_GET['area']);
if ($selection == "time"){
echo "Not working yet please come back at a later update.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The operator "=" is not proper.
You should use "===" to check equality.

```
<?php
$selection=$_GET['area'];
if ($selection === 'time'){
echo 'Not working yet please come back at a later update.';
}
?>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not helpful. Explain what you did.

Answer (score 0):

Always use `==` or `===` operators to check conditions

```
$selection=$_GET['area'];
if ($selection=="time"){
    echo "Not working yet please come back at a later update.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this.

```
if ($selection=="time"){

    $selection="time"
```

this assigns $selection variable a value "time".

Answer (score 0):

you forgot one = your code should be

```
$selection = $_GET['area'];
if ( $selection == 'time' ) {
    echo 'Now working yet please comde back at a later update';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using `=`you are assigning 'time' to $selection which always returnes true
use `==` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
if ($selection=="time")
```

instead of

```
if ($selection="time")
```